# how to use angluarJS to get the parent element when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, this

I am actually trying to use angular to use ajax and it's something like deleting comments / posts.

I searched online and there are lots of tutorials then I figured how the tutorial was doing would refresh the page.

I know if I am doing this by using jQuery that I can just use something like `$(this).parent().remove()` or something similar to remove the element from the dom without refreshing and the backend will do it's job.
But with angular js, how can I say something such as `$(this).parent().remove()`.

I tried `console.log` the above it returns something weird, like `m{
$$ChildScope
:
b()
$$childHead
:
b
$$childTail
:
b
$$listenerCount
:
Object
$$listeners
:
Object
$$nextSibling
:
null
$$prevSibling
:
null
$$watchers
:
Array[5]`

and so one.

Can someone please give me a hand?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Following example will remove whole `<div>` when button is clicked.

```
<div ng-if="removed">
   <span>Hello</span>        
   <button ng-click="removed=true">Remove me</button>
</div>
```